# Why i can't connect websocket through proxy?

Tags: c#, .net, websocket

How can I connect websocket through proxy (without can)

```
var url = new Uri("ws://irc-ws.chat.twitch.tv:80");
        var factory = new Func<ClientWebSocket>(() => new ClientWebSocket
        {
            Options =
            {
            Proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy("23.239.20.205",80),

            }
        });

        var client = new WebsocketClient(url,factory);
        client.Start();
        client.Send("PASS oauth:xxx");
        client.Send("NICK xxx");
        client.Send("JOIN #xxx");
        client.MessageReceived.Where(x => 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine(x.Text); 
            return true; 
        }).Subscribe();
        while (true)
        {
            client.Send("PRIVMSG #xxx :" + Console.ReadLine());
        }
```

Comment: The proxy may not be reachable.  Try to ping from cmd.exe >Ping 23.239.20.205

Comment: @jdweng 0% lose

Comment: See if it is inside your DNS.  from cmd.exe >IPCONFIG/ALL.  Then ping the DNS server to see the IP.  The proxy IP and the DNS server should start with same IP address.

Comment: From the code you posted it looks like you're creating a factory with the proxy config, but then not using it at all. Instead you create a `WebSocketClient` and use that instread.

Comment: @ekke before copy code i use this